# My PC restarts randomly

Tags: memory, graphics-card, cpu, power-supply

I bought a desktop 1 year ago. I used it and it worked very fine. After 6 months it suddenly shut down without blue screen and was responding to restarts. yet it is not solved but I tried a lot to detect the problem. After opening the PC it takes 1 to 3 hours to start the problem and gradually it frequently restarts within seconds. The strange fact is that it doesn't restart when it's taken to the computer shop I bought it from. I need to mention that...

1. I didn't have grounding in my house.
2. the voltage of electricity sometimes fluctuates.
3. the restart first started happening during a overload work.
4. restart happens in boot option also.
5. restart happens even without any work like watching movie or listening song.
6. the ups has avr inside but sometimes it doesn't support the PC, sometimes it does, strangely it never gave up in the PC shop.
7. I haven't changed the processor cooling liquid yet.
8. I have other computers but they go fine however they are way low configured.

my spec:

- Intel® Core™ i7-3820 Processor (10M Cache, up to 3.80 GHz).
- Intel’s DX79TO mobo.
- Asus Nvidia GeForce GT 640 Graphics Card (2GB DDR3).
- 720 WT power supply.
- 24 gb ram (8X8X8)1600.
- 1200v ups with avr.

Data after 5 min of normal running:
[image: Data after 5 min of normal running]

Answer (score 0):

There could be dust in your fan. This is a common problem in areas with a lot of dust in the air. The reason it doesn't restart when taken to the computer shop is that it is not overworked.

Advice: Remove the computer fan (or ask the computer shop to do it) and clean it thoroughly. Even a little dust can cause the fan to be less effective and can slow it down. Overheating from faulty fan is the most common cause of restarting desktop.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it sounds like you've installed a liquid cooling system?

I'd recommend running a monitoring tool that reports the temperatures inside the PC. Then run a test suite on it to load it and see what temperatures are being reported. This would seem to be the most likely issue.

Let us know the outcome and we will probably be able to help further.

If you have a UPS, you shouldn't be getting power fluctuation problems. However, it /is/ possible that your power supply is either faulty or not performing to a decent spec. Was it a good make of PS?

There is also a possibility of a faulty mobo where higher temperatures are causing a faulty connection to fail when under load. These things are notoriously hard to track down. Make sure that you are getting enough air through the case. Don't run without the case closed as you wont be driving air across the components. Also make sure that, if you have multiple fans, they are all wired the right way round. It is surprisingly common to find a fan wired backwards so that air isn't being driven right through the case.

Report back the CPU and case temperatures & the mobo voltages reported from a monitoring tool so we can help further.

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10201831578701296&set=a.10201831577701271.1073741831.1537431266&type=3&theater

Comment: I beg pardon if any other site's link is invalid. i gave an image after running HW monitor through facebook above. i just ran the hw monitor and observed 5 minutes then capture the print screen. the power supply is average++ but not too good. they say it should be run a test suite like p95 for 12 hours at least. but my pc shut down within 1 hour most of the time. what kind of test suite can i use that works within some minutes?

Comment: I've added your pic to the question. I think you need to run a test suite and then try to capture the same data before it crashes. What is showing looks perfectly normal at present, maybe slightly higher than average but within normal ranges.